# Getting a list of times between two times

Tags: java

I have a range of times with a start and an end, both of which are `java.sql.Time` objects`. I want to populate a JComboBox with a list of times between them, in intervals of 15 minutes. For instance, if the start is 11:00 and the end is 12:00, I want the options in the JComboBox to be 11:00, 11:15, 11:30, 11:45 and 12:00.

Whats the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: I dont know if it is the most efficient way, but I would do an Array of JComboBox, where in each element I would have a "time". What do you think?

Comment: 2018 comment: today you’d prefer to use the modern `LocalTime` class rather than the long outdated and poorly designed `java.sql.Time`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.sql.Time` extends from `java.util.Date`, therefore you can use it within other classes that accept `Date`.

Here, I've used a `Calendar` to simply modify the miniute field by 15 minute intervals until I reach the desired end time...

```
List<java.sql.Time> intervals = new ArrayList<>(25);
// These constructors are deprecated and are used only for example
java.sql.Time startTime = new java.sql.Time(11, 0, 0);
java.sql.Time endTime = new java.sql.Time(12, 0, 0);

intervals.add(startTime);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(startTime);
while (cal.getTime().before(endTime)) {
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    intervals.add(new java.sql.Time(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
}

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
for (java.sql.Time time : intervals) {
    System.out.println(sdf.format(time));
}
```

This will output

```
11:00
11:15
11:30
11:45
12:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Twisted a bit on your question: make a List containing all integers in 5-interval, between 2 integer:

First, we can know how many number there will be, and allocate the list accordingly:
(all in psuedo code)

```
// assume begin and end is at the boundary of interval. 
int noOfElement = (begin - end)/5 + 1;
List<Integer> resultList = new ArrayList<>(noOfElement);
```

Then populate the values in the list:

```
for (int i = begin; i <= end ; i += 5) {
  resultList.add(i);
}
```

resultList will then contains all the values you want.

If you can understand this example, there is nothing special making similar logic which handles Date

Some more hints to you: look into `Date#toTime()`, and `Date(long Date)`

Comment: Also look at joda time's periods and durations. It makes it trivial to add, say, 15 minutes to a time stamp.

Comment: @MichaelDeardeuff I'd rather have a long, and add (15 * 60 * 1000) to get the next time.  It looks as trivial and as readable in such case :)